# how to displays 3 different divs in each slide in owl carousel in wordpress loop?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, owl-carousel-2

I need to create something like this picture, i want to do this but i dont know what should to do

[image]

```
<div class="owl-carousel">

    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="left-side">
                <div class="full-width">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumb-sm' ); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="full-width">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumb-sm' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumb-lg' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>`

    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div>`
```